# Should sensitive information such as credit card number be encrypted even when transmitting using https?

Tags: encryption, payment-processing, pci-compliance, network-security

This is in context of an application in cloud communicating to internal application through vpn over https connection. (Both the applications are of same organization)

So, even when using the above things, is it required add an additional layer of security by encrypting the credit card information so that the other application needs to decrypt it using predefined key?

Comment: yes and no, depends on what are you doing.

Comment: In which scenarios it could be useful? this is not end user communication, this is communication between two software systems of an organization through code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I should encrypt it to avoid attack of type 'man-in-the-middle'.

Comment: @Nicolas More details, please.

Comment: @Nicholas most cryptographic protocols have endpoint authentication to prevent Man-in-the-Middle attacks. Even MVC has an anti-forgery token you can send.

Comment: Is there a straight way to move this question to Information Security with out re posting there?

Comment: Intercepting and readnig https packets seems possible: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server/67534#67534 with commercial software. My position is 'take all reasonable mesure to protect valuable data'.

Comment: So, in this case the concerned systems should only trust each other's certificates and nothing else, that can be possible in our scenarios since both the systems are managed by same organization.

Comment: @Nicolas So you're talking about SSL proxies. That requires an already compromised system (e.g. your employer's customised box). If you're entering sensitive data on an already compromised system, SSL proxies are the least of your worries. If your employer has customised your box to accept proxy certificates, they may as well have installed a key logger to capture your data before it's being encrypted. That's not a credible scenario to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with credit card numbers then you really need to follow [PCIDSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf). 4.1 states that when sending cardholder information over open or public networks it must be "appropriately" encrypted. It only states HTTPS (so SSL/TLS must be enabled).

I appreciate that you are not limiting your question to only credit card information.

I would say that for most things HTTPS is absolutely fine. I have had to encrypt a second user's password before (to validate information on a form that the first user entered, a bit like a signature) but that is not related to what you are talking about using HTTPS and encryption with.

Your question might be worth posting over at [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So, as far as PCI is concerned extra encryption is not a requirement. While it's no harm to add an extra bit of encryption, the key management will be a hurdle...which complicates the issues, for example AES key.